# Chinese phrase meaning 钓到凯子了

Tags: meaning, phrase

I am still reading a Chinese book and found something I cannot translate. Possible you can help me. Thanks in advance. The phrase: "钓到凯子了".
P.S. thanks all helped me last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiktionary:

[**釣凱子**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%87%A3%E5%87%B1%E5%AD%90#Chinese)

> (slang) to pick up men; to hit on a man

Comment: Thanks! Thought of it but wasn't sure..

Answer (score 0):

凯子 is street slang for a man who is 1) an older person with money to spend. The person is fond of and easily seduced by women (especially young women) and willing to use money/gift exchange for his pleasure, usually sexually oriented. 2) a young fellow from a rich family. The person will willingly spend money and cover the expense incurred by the so-called friends/brothers he met on the street to show off his generosity towards friends and gain the "number one" position in the group.

钓 is "fishing", "钓到凯子了" is saying - "got a fish (凯子)" through fishing.

Comment: Wow, great one!